# AVX with three operands in GAS Syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, avx, gnu-assembler

what does an assembly instruction like

```
vfmsub231sd (%rsi), %xmm1, %xmm0
```

do? I am confused because the 231 should indicate A=BC-A but it's doing something else, maybe because of GAS Syntax instead of Intel (where i got this information for the 231).

Comment: I think it's doing C=AB-C (?)

Comment: Basically, the operand order is reversed in AT&T syntax.  So this is equal to `vfmsub231sd xmm0, xmm1, [rsi]` in Intel syntax.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now.